# PHP variable scope and IFs

Tags: php

I have roughtly something similar to this:

```
function get_gender ($gid){ 
    $return= '';

...some code ..

    if ($male !== 0 && $female !== 0){
        $return = 'mixed';
    }else if ($male !== 0 && $female == 0){
        $return = 'male';
    }
    return $return;

}
```

I know for a fact that one of the condition is met, so i assumed the $return variable would be updated. Though it always comes back empty. Is this a problem of scope ?

Comment: what is `$male` and `$female` set to? its not very clear.

Comment: If `$male === 0`, it will not enter either of those conditions. Do an echo inside the `if else` blocks to see if PHP ever gets there

Comment: Also, why don't you do an explicit `return` from the `if-else` block instead of having this `$return` variable? It will save you a couple of steps, a variable and IMO it's cleaner.

Comment: @NullUserException: there used to be (maybe still is) a school of thought that says a function should have only one return point, so what silkAdmin does is exactly what is recommended by this school.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nope, this isn't a scope-problem. your variables must be set wrong, so the conditions arn't met. maybe thats because the result should be a female (i can't see an option for that), or it's because you're using explicit type-sensitive conditions(maybe your variables contain strings ander - try to make `===` to `==` and `!==` to `==` and see if something changes)

to proof this, try to add another `else{ }` and set `$return` to "oh noez" (or something else).

Answer (score 4):

In your code, if `$male` is zero, `$female` is never checked, and neither assignment is run, leaving `$return` empty.

Comment: Thanks, it was actually coming from how i was loading the variable i was checking.. Nothing to do with the code though you all made good points ! Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

No, it's a debugging problem. Scope has nothing to do here since it doesn't change (at least not in the code you provided).

Try this:

```
if ($male !== 0 && $female !== 0){
    $return = 'mixed';
    echo 'Return: ' . $return;
}else if ($male !== 0 && $female == 0){
    $return = 'male';
    echo 'Return: ' . $return;
} else {
    echo 'None of the conditions met';
}
```

Besides, don't you want booleans for this (true, false) instead of explicit integer checking?

Answer (score 1):

No scope should not be a problem here.

More than likely your problem lies in your conditions. Particularly the use of [strict equality](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) (i.e. `!==`).